# instead of re-throwing a user-defined exception can we re-throw SQLException and ClassNotFound Exceptions in Dao?

Tags: java, exception

```
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupportImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Override
    public int save(Employee employee) throws EmployeeException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(?,?,?)";
        Connection conToUse = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        int status = 0;
        try {
            conToUse = getConnection();
            ps = conToUse.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, employee.getEmpNo());
            ps.setString(2, employee.getEmpName());
            ps.setLong(3, employee.getEmpSal());
            status = ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new EmployeeException(
                    "%%% Exception occured in EmployeeDao save() %%% " + e);
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(ps);
        }
        return status;
    }

}
```

In the example code, the class EmployeeDaoImpl is inserting a record into a database. if any exception raises, it is throwing  EmployeeException, which is an application exception, to the service layer. What is the need of throwing userdefined exceptions? We can throw SQLexceptions also in this case, is it correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to throw a user defined exception in this instance. The SQLException should suffice.

The User Defined Exception would make more sense if the Connection object threw your defined exception.

As long as you catch the exception and do something with it that is all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be throwing ClassNotFoundExceptions because the DAO shouldn't be responsible for creating database connections. I would hope getConnection is retrieving an existing connection from somewhere, maybe a threadlocal, where it was put earlier in the request. If it *is* creating a connection then it isn't closing it, which would be bad. Also you should be using a connection pool (again resulting in moving the code that could throw a ClassNotFoundException to somewhere outside the DAO).

For most SQLExceptions you can't do anything about them but let them bubble up, canceling the current unit of work, and then catch and log it in an exception handler, so having a checked exception is an annoyance. Spring does the right thing here, it translates SQLExceptions into more meaningful but unchecked DataAccessExceptions where different subtypes are used for different types of errors. If you find yourself needing to catch an exception thrown when an RI constraint is violated you would catch a `DataIntegrityViolationException` without having to worry about what SQLState your database vendor uses for this, because Spring translated it for you already.

With this unchecked DataAccessException there's no reason to have an application specific wrapper exception anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes these kind of exceptions can be thrown as is.
If you have a Ui frontend or some sort of client, then it make sense to wrap it as a user exception and throw.